# PHP7: Static class function can't be called/seen until class is instanced

Tags: php, oop, php-7, spl-autoload-register, php-7.2

I have a custom class called `Error` that I autoload before anything else. In my custom class, I have a constructor and a singleton Get function like this:

```
class Error
{
    // Singleton object. Leave $me alone.
    private static $me;

    public $errors; // Array of errors
    public $style;  // CSS rules to apply to error elements

    private function __construct($style = "border:1px solid red;")
    {
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->style = $style;          
    }

    // Get Singleton object
    public static function getError()
    {
        if(is_null(self::$me))
            self::$me = new Error();

        return self::$me;
    }
    //...
}
```

In my master include, I've always prepared a singleton of this custom class before the core logic:

```
$Error = Error::getError();
```

However, in PHP 7 this is now giving me an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Error::getError()

Can you help me understand why this doesn't work anymore? I've tried this instead to check whether the Error class is being loaded at all, and it does work (and call the constructor):

```
$Error = new Error();
```

Somehow I can't call the static class function unless I've instanced this class. This will break a lot of other logic I have if that's truly a change in php7.

Comment: PHP7 has a built-in `Error` class. You are probably experiencing namespace errors.  Does your `Error` class exist in a custom namespace? http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php

Comment: If you are in a position to upgrade permanently to PHP 7 (your code no longer needs to run under 5.x) perhaps you could just adopt the internal `Error` class in place of your own.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks, that seems the most likely cause, what an unfortunate clash. Fortunately that's easy for me to work past, since only one place calls the static initialiser function for my Error class. I'll check if this is the cause. Feel free to add the "built-in" namespace comment as an answer. I'll mark it if this let's me fix the issue.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski happy to confirm that you were 100% correct. It clashed with the built-in Error class in PHP 7. Minor refactoring resolved that and the rest of the application now runs in my PHP 7 environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PHP 7, PHP includes a built-in `Error` class which appears to be in conflict with your application's `Error` class.

[PHP pre-defined `Error` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php)

If your own application's class is not defined within a custom namespace and you are attempting to call `Error::getError()`, PHP will assume you mean the built-in class which has no defined `getError()` method. (It does have a similar `getMessage()` non-static method).

You may work around this by [adding a custom `namespace`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) to your application, which is a recommended practice anyway. Or if your application has no requirement to continue running under PHP 5.x, consider refactoring it to use the built-in `Error` class functionality instead.